# If a figure was mostly increasing, with occasional decreases, can I say "it generally increased during the period"?

Tags: grammar

For example, in this chart, can I write, "Spending on health research generally increased during the period"?

My concern is mostly about how I use the word "generally" here.

[image]

Comment: It's grammatical but whether it's accurate enough is a matter of opinion. IMO, not.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say something like "Spending on health research steadily increased in the 20-year period from 1984 to 2004 but then began to fall."

Comment: It depends what you're trying to prove. The overall level of health research increased over the period. But did it increase in real terms? Are you interested in the current trend? "Generally" is sufficiently vague you can use it here, but you should think what meaning you want to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as a senior data analyst, I would be happy with that statement. The chart does show a decline during the last period, but the period immediately before was a 'spike' that represented a much greater increase than the steady climb in the earlier periods *and* the drop brought the figure down to a point that was still higher than where the data was before that spike. So, during that period, the metric did 'generally' increase. But I would expect some narrative to explain that spike, as it may also explain the sharp decline afterwards. You could also include a trend line or maybe even consider more data points so that the cause of that spike can be isolated and perhaps more easily explained.

From a purely English grammar point of view, you might be better with the word 'broadly' instead of 'generally'. The latter means without reference to specifics, and you are using specific data to support that statement. But the former means without reference to *exceptions*, and that data spike and subsequent drop is an exception.